# Distinguish methods and properties

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, eslint, static-code-analysis

**The Problem:**

I'm currently improving the [`valid-expect` rule](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine/blob/master/lib/rules/valid-expect.js) for the `eslint-plugin-jasmine` package trying to handle one more invalid Jasmine `expect()` usage when a matcher is not called:

```
expect(true).toBeDefined;
```

Valid usage:

```
expect(true).toBeDefined();
```

I'm getting pretty close - I can determine that there is a member expression on the `expect()`:

```
// matcher was not called
MemberExpression: function (node) {
  if (node.object && node.object.callee.name === 'expect') {
    console.log(node.property)
  }
}
```

But the `node.property` in both valid and invalid cases is of an `Identifier` type:

```
Node {
  type: 'Identifier',
  start: 13,
  end: 24,
  loc: 
   SourceLocation {
     start: Position { line: 1, column: 13 },
     end: Position { line: 1, column: 24 } },
  range: [ 13, 24 ],
  name: 'toBeDefined' }
```

And there is nothing obvious indicating that this is a property or a method.

**The Question:**

How can I determine if a property is callable or not in `ESLint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect(true).toBeDefined` is parsed into a `MemberExpression` node, but `expect(true).toBeDefined()` is parser into a `CallExpression`. I'm not really 100% sure why this is happening, but in the second case, it seems to think that the whole statement up until opening brackets is one single `CallExpression`, I would expect there to be two separate `CallExpression`, but that doesn't seems to be the case.

So what you can do is listen to `CallExpression` and check that callee is `Identifier` with name `expect`. And then check if it's grandparent is a `MemberExpression` or another `CallExpression`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for looking into this! I actually had to go to the parent of the parent and check the type..the `node.parent.parent.type` would be `CallExpression` if this is a method call and `ExpressionStatement` if a property..is this what you meant? Note that `node.parent.type` would still be `MemberExpression` in both cases..(https://gist.github.com/alecxe/f34fe3140ab13ac7ab5626fb8fcd637c#file-valid-expect-js-L20)

Comment: Yes, you have to go to the grandparent node. Sorry about that.

Comment: Alright, that works, covered with tests and send the PR. Thanks.